# MVC Model - Regular Expression for minimum of 1 character and max of 5

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to have a

1. minimum of 1 character
2. maximum of 5 characters

using MVC Model Validator.
I have tried using:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-z]{1,5}$", ErrorMessage="Insert range of 1 to 5 Characters")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Results:

**A**. Maximum works, but the Minimum fails.

**B**. Works fine if I set minimum to 2 characters (and have min of 2 chars inserted)

**C**. In a console app,it works fine.

I'm not sure if this is a bug within JQuery.

Is there an alternate (using Regual expressions though)?

Comment: Are there any other validations active? Perhaps there's another one that is insisting longer than 1

Comment: That sounds like a weird issue. How about forcing the first character: `@"^[a-z][a-z]{0,4}$"`

Comment: this is what is generated from html - <input name="UserName" id="UserName" type="text" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-z]{1,5}$" data-val-regex="please insert range of 1 to 5 Characters" data-val="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

use Model validator attribute, StringLength when defining your model

```
[StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
```

where parametres are like this: [StringLength(MaxLength, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]

Complete model property

```
[Required]
[StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\n\r\0-9_ ]+$")]
public String Username {get; set;}
```

For purely regular  expression
use

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{1,5}$")]
```

Comment: Thanks Rex, but is there a way of purely using the [RegularExpression] attribute?

Comment: @user532104 checking for that :)

Comment: @user532104 check the answer for purely regular expression.

Comment: Good try Rex but it failed too. Not sure if Jquery may be the issue?